# SCP to copy a file from Linux to windows is failing with Permission Denied error

Tags: permissions, ssh, connection, copy, scp

I am using `scp` command to copy a file from Linux to Windows. It's failing with the mentioned log.

Steps accomplished:

- Installed `openssh` in windows
- copied `id_rsa.pub` key to Linux box under `.ssh/authorized_keys`
- File permissions all set to full control
- `sshd_config` file has these settings:

  ```
  RSAAuthentication yes
  PubkeyAuthentication yes
  password authentication yes
  ```

Command used:

```
scp -v /app/lib/jenkins/jobs/ChromeDriver-Version-Upgrade/jobs/ChromeDriver-Version-Upgrade/workspace/chromedriver_win32.zip/ User@10.1.X.XXX:/C:/
```

Logs:

```
Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host 10.1.xx.XXX, user XX_dmin, command scp -v -t /C:/
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 3: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 10.1.16.149 [10.1.16.149] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.5
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.5 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=20 dh_need=20
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=20 dh_need=20
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 96:bf:21:bb:02:ce:e8:fb:54:3f:58:40:8c:25:6b:1f
debug1: Host '10.1.XX.XXX' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/known_hosts:36
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
lost connection
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: *File permissions all set to full control*
 may be the wrong thing to do, see [here](https://superuser.com/a/215506/748149) for the correct permission settings.

Comment: Doublecheck your client settings at `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`. When key authentication fails, you should at least get a prompt for a password. Can you `ssh` in using either a password or a key? (ie, try ssh instead of scp to simplify the problem)

Comment: You need to use the ssh key with scp also : 

    `scp -v -i id_rsa /app/lib/jenkins/jobs/ChromeDriver-Version-Upgrade/jobs/ChromeDriver-Version-Upgrade/workspace/chromedriver_win32.zip/ User@10.1.X.XXX:/C:/`

Comment: Maybe the user you use just has no permissions on `app/lib/jenkins/jobs......`?

Comment: The key message in all the posted question is "Permission denied (publickey)" . The keys are not set up properly.

Comment: barrycarter : Am able to ssh in linux server and its prompting for a password. The issue that i mentioned is via a jenkins job.

Comment: HI everyone, i have corrected the file permissions for both .ssh and authorized_key files and also tried ssh ,nothing has resolved the issue, Please help if you have any other inputs.